# Alarm is not calling in android

Tags: java, android, android-intent, alarmmanager

```
AlarmManager alarmManager=(AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);

        Intent alarmIntent=new Intent(context,UpdateTables.class);

        PendingIntent pendingIntent=PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context,0,alarmIntent,PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

        alarmManager.cancel(pendingIntent);

        Calendar alarmStartTime = Calendar.getInstance();

        alarmStartTime.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());

        //midnight
        alarmStartTime.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 19);
        alarmStartTime.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 18);
        alarmStartTime.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);

        if(Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis()>alarmStartTime.getTimeInMillis())
        {
            alarmStartTime.add(Calendar.DATE,1);
        }

        Log.i("TIME IS ",Long.toString(alarmStartTime.getTimeInMillis()));


        System.out.println("Updating table time "+alarmStartTime);
        System.out.println("Time in millseconds "+alarmStartTime.getTimeInMillis());


        alarmManager.setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC,alarmStartTime.getTimeInMillis(),AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY,pendingIntent);

        Log.d("Alarm","Set for midnight");
```

This alarm is firing other receiver i.e. UpdateTables.java(This is working)

Now inside the UpdateTables.java which is also creating the alarm and passing intent to the another receiver. But the receiver is not receiving the intent.

```
 //show notification for the test ans follow up
        ArrayList<Action> notificationData=dbHelper.fetchTestAndFollowUpTime();


        for (int actionitem=0;actionitem<notificationData.size();actionitem++){

            Action actionItem=notificationData.get(actionitem);
            long hourRemainingCompeleteTask=TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toHours(actionItem.getActionEndDate()-Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis());

            System.out.println("Action is "+actionItem.getAction_name());
            System.out.println("test time is "+actionItem.getActionEndDate());
            System.out.println("Current time "+Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis());
            System.out.println("Hour remaining "+hourRemainingCompeleteTask);

            if (Long.valueOf(hourRemainingCompeleteTask).compareTo(24L)<0){
                //means remaining time is less than 24 hr.
                setAlarmToCallNotificationService(context,actionitem+alarmLastRequestCode+5,actionItem.getAction_name(),actionItem.getCatagory());
            }else {
                //in the else.
                setAlarmToCallNotificationService(context,actionitem+alarmLastRequestCode+5,actionItem.getAction_name(),actionItem.getCatagory());
            }
        }



 private static void init(Context ctx){
        if (alarmManager==null)
            alarmManager=(AlarmManager) ctx.getSystemService(ctx.ALARM_SERVICE);
    }
@SuppressLint("NewApi")
    private void setAlarmToCallNotificationService(Context context, int request_code, String notificationText, String notificationTitle) {
            init(context);

        Log.i("Inside notification,","Yes");

        Intent intent = new Intent(context, notificationService.class);
        intent.putExtra("Notification_title",notificationTitle);
        intent.putExtra("Notification_text",notificationText);


        //hit the notification At the 8.00 in the morning
        Calendar notificationCalendar=Calendar.getInstance();
        notificationCalendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY,11);
        notificationCalendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE,55);
        notificationCalendar.set(Calendar.SECOND,0);

        Long time=notificationCalendar.getTimeInMillis();

        System.out.println("NOTIFICATION Time is "+notificationCalendar.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY)+" "+notificationCalendar.get(Calendar.MINUTE));
        Log.i("Target",time.toString());

        //final int _id = (int) System.currentTimeMillis();
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, request_code, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);

        int currentapiVersion = android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT;
        if (currentapiVersion < android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT){
            alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, time, pendingIntent);
        } else {
            if (currentapiVersion < android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
                alarmManager.setExact(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, time, pendingIntent);
            } else {
                alarmManager.setExactAndAllowWhileIdle(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, time, pendingIntent);
            }
        }

        //AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        //alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, time, pendingIntent);

    }
```

But the problem is,updateTables.java receiver is not firing the notificationService receiver

```
public class notificationService extends BroadcastReceiver {

    public static String TAG="notificationService";
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        String notificatioTitle=intent.getExtras().getString("Notification_title");
        String notificationMsg=intent.getExtras().getString("Notification_text");

        Log.i(TAG,"Notification title "+notificatioTitle);
        Log.i(TAG,"Notification msg "+notificationMsg);

        NotificationCompat.Builder notification=new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
                .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
                .setContentTitle(notificatioTitle)
                .setContentText(notificationMsg);

        NotificationManager mNotificationManager =(NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        mNotificationManager.notify(0,notification.build());
    }


}
```

**Manifest File**

```
<receiver android:name=".UpdateTables"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="true">

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
            </intent-filter>

        </receiver>

<receiver android:name=".notificationService"
            android:enabled="true">
```

Output of ./adb shell dumpsys alarm:

```
 RTC #19: Alarm{3788170 type 1 when 1484142480449 user.com.hlthee}

    tag=*alarm*:user.com.hlthee/.UpdateTables

    type=1 whenElapsed=+23h56m29s342ms when=2017-01-11 19:18:00

    window=-1 repeatInterval=86400000 count=0

    operation=PendingIntent{3e5f6ce9: PendingIntentRecord{7068d6e user.com.hlthee broadcastIntent}}



u0a195:user.com.hlthee +79ms running, 3 wakeups:

    +69ms 0 wakes 1 alarms: *alarm*:user.com.hlthee/.UpdateTables

    +10ms 3 wakes 3 alarms: *walarm*:user.com.hlthee/services.notificationService
```

I have change the code according to answer given here but still alarm is not rang.

Comment: I can't understand if your code does not trigger at all the notification or it triggers but you can't see it. Does the program enter into the setAlarmToCallNotificationService method? Are you able to see the logs generated by these two lines?         Log.i(TAG,"Notification title "+notificatioTitle); Log.i(TAG,"Notification msg "+notificationMsg); ?

Comment: yes it is entering into the fuction setAlarmToCallNotificationService() and printing the log. but it is not entering in to the notificationService broadcast receiver

Answer (score 0):

To be sure your event is calling use this method:

```
private static AlarmManager am;
    private static void init(Context ctx){
        if (am == null)
            am = (AlarmManager) ctx.getSystemService(Activity.ALARM_SERVICE);
    }
    @SuppressLint("NewApi")
    public static void startbyalarmWake(Context ctx, long nexttim) {
        init(ctx);

        Intent intent = new Intent(ctx,BRWake.class);

        PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(ctx, SOMEID, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);

        int currentapiVersion = android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT;
        if (currentapiVersion < android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT){
            am.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, nexttime, pi);
        } else {
            if (currentapiVersion < android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
                am.setExact(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, nexttime, pi);
            } else {
                am.setExactAndAllowWhileIdle(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, nexttime, pi);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: I change the code accordingly but still notificationService server is calling

Comment: I change the code accordingly but still notificationService service  is not calling